# C# properties. "if (value is double)" is always true

Tags: c#, properties

So, I'm supposed to check for erroneous value but I get the message that "if (value is double)" is always true, what am I doing wrong?

```
 public double _ProductCost
    {
        get
        { return Cost;}
        set
        {
            if (value is double)
            {
                Cost = value;
            }
            else
            {
                NumberServed = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("erroneous value!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you expecting someone to pass in a `double` that *isn't* a `double`?

Comment: Passing in something else than a `double` would be a *compile-time* error

Comment: Following along with @Servy...  You have the `_ProductCost` property typed as a `double`.  That means that `value` is _always_ a `double`.  So, your test (if value is a double) will always succeed.

Comment: Perhaps "erroneous" (from what I assume is your homework assignment) means "negative" or "`double.Nan`"?

Comment: Compiler stops _Product = <non double value>, therefore value is always double when this check is performed.

Comment: Are you trying to cast a string to double and validate? If so - look at double.TryParse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a property setter, where you're looking at syntax like this:

```
foo._ProductCost = bar;
```

C# is a strongly typed language. If `bar` is anything other than a `double`, or at least implicitly convertible to a `double`, this is already a **compile-time** error. The only way this code can ever actually execute is if the compiler has *already confirmed* `value` is a `double`.

I suspect the testing you need to do here is for unreasonable cost values (will a  product ever have a negative cost?) or at the user-interface part of the code, where you test a string in a TextBox somewhere can convert before even trying to assign it.

That, or your manager is a former PHP developer who comes from a world without good type checking.

Comment: I'm being asked to create a few properties and then im told to

"Please note that erroneous values in the numerical fields must be recognised. In the event the number entered using the set property is erroneous, a default value of zero should be stored and an appropriate message should be emitted to the console."

So I thought I was supposed to include it there but I guess I'm supposed to do that in main program?
I'm a little bit confused because I don't have any instructions to actually create anything in main

Comment: @Staur: Consider adding something like `if (value <= 0.0) { /* do something with the invalid product cost */ }`.  Your `value` will always be a double, but it may not be a value that makes any sense (like a zero or negative product cost)

Comment: @Flydog57 Oh, I guess this is what he means... Really sorry for taking time out of your day because of me being unable to understand what im being asked and thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Staur: depending on what you are using to manage your user interface, there may be a standard way of doing _Validation_.  There isn't for console apps (because no one writes User interface in a console app - despite how teachers/professors seem to like them), but there are standard ways to do this for Windows Forms, WPF and the various forms of ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

`value` is an *implied* parameter to the setter. The type of the parameter will be the type of the property (`double` in this case).

The setter is compiled behind-the-scenes to:

```
public void set_ProductCost(double value)
{
    /// setter code here
}
```

So passing something *other* than a `double` to the property setter would be a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - but I think maybe you are trying to do something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "abc";
        var value = GetProductCost(input); 
        Console.WriteLine($"Value is: {value}");

        input = "123.45";
        value = GetProductCost(input);
        Console.WriteLine($"Value is: {value}");

        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }

    private static double GetProductCost(string input)
    {
        double value = 0; 
        if (!double.TryParse(input, out value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("erroneous value!");
        }

        return value; 
    }
```